# How to run Auth::logoutOtherDevices() without password?

Tags: laravel

I **need** to run Auth::logoutOtherDevices() without informing user's password, because the user's in this app I'm building simply **don't have a password** (they login with custom personal usernames and only administrators have a password).

I've tried messing up with Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard file, but nothing changes and I can't get my head around it. Also, I can't find someone online that had the same issue as I have, to get some inspiration...

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to SO ... what version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: php artisan -v => Laravel Framework 7.28.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you well.
For Simple user add a default value for password column for users not an administrator so.

Lets say default password is 123456 so you will pass Auth::logoutOtherDevices('123456') for all users not an administrator

Comment: thanks! your insight helped me to do what I already should've done..